I am looking for a way to detect screen sharing on a tab
I am working on an assessment web app and I need a way to tell if a student/user tries or is currently sharing the tab with an ongoing assessment or is sharing the screen.
This is to prevent cheating, and I know platforms like Netflix and some other online exam web apps can blackout or notify the page of a screen share or screen record.
I have not been able to find a solution, and I don't know if I'm not searching correctly.
P.S. We already have checks for fullscreen, tab switch and window blur, but on the off chance that the screen is shared before beginning the assessment, it's important to know.
Thank you for your help.

Widevine allows to protect your content, it's used by netflix, disney and others. You also can check on the 'Remote Proctoring Softwares' side.
